# python How to divide an array into random sizes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to divide the array into a random size rather than a certain size. What can I do?

```
B= np.array([[0 ,1, 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0],
[1, 0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0],
[0, 1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
[0, 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1],
[1, 0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0],
[1, 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1],
[0, 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
[1, 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1],
[0, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0]])

new = [2,1,3,5,6,7,9,8]
B1 = np.array([[B[i][j]for j in new] for i in new])

result = []
for _ in xrange(0,5):
      split_ = B1[0:i+1,0:i+1]
      result.append(split_)
```

Comment: It's a 2d array, so you mean you want randomly sized "rectangles" from that "square"?

Comment: Roll a bunch of [dice](https://xkcd.com/221/)!

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, the point is that the size of the divided squares is divided into random sizes.

Comment: @johny Non-overlapping rectangles?

Comment: @StephenCowley 
Yes, that's right. I want to create an independent rectangle.